# its not printing 0,1,2,3,4,5...10 its printing 10 ten times

Tags: javascript

- I am new to js
- I thought below code will output 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 with a gap of 10 ms.
- but it's not printing like that it's printing 10 ten times.
- is it due to set a timeout or something else?
- can you guys tell me why it's happening...it will help me so much with understanding js

```or-tag-here
for( var i=0; i< 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log(i);
    }, 10);

}
```

Comment: loop will complete before first setTimeout even fires at which time `i` will already be at it's maximum

Comment: @charlietfl I have given i< 10 but why its printing 10

Answer (score 1):

It's because of closure, you should do something like that

```
for( var i=0; i< 10; i++) { 
    (function(j){
       setTimeout(function(){ console.log(j); }, 10);
    }(i));
}
```

This is basic javascript closure, you can read more here [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

The problem is that the for loop finishes first, so at the end, `i` will equal 10. After that, the `setTimeout` functions will get called and when they check the value of `i`, they'll find it equal to the last value from the for loop which 10. 
What I did is called an `IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)` which creates a new variable for the scope of the `setTimeout` function, so when the timeout comes, it finds its own variable that hasn't changed.

Comment: thanks for your reply...here I did not assign value for j but how its printing for j...I read the link which you provided but still I am not getting...can you tell in simple terms...sorry :(